# Failed to install .bna on second peer from a fabric multi org network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to deploy to an hyperledger fabric network with composer. A fabric network composed by:

- 1 Orderer
- 2 cas
- 2 peers : peer0.org1.example.com, peer0.org2.example.com (from two distinct organizations)

Everything on my local machine.

I can make all the peers join the same channel, and i can use a sample chaincode from fabric without any errors (instantiate, invoke, query).

Then comes composer-cli commands. Each of them is ran in a distinct composer-cli container. Here's the script (with PRIV_KEY1, PRIV_KEY2 and COMPOSER-VERSION replaced by the correct values)

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  --network composer_default \
  -v $(pwd)/.vld-card-store:/home/composer/.composer \
  -v $(pwd)/vldstage:/home/composer/vldstage \
  -v $(pwd)/json:/home/composer/json \
  -v $(pwd)/fabric-dev-servers/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp:/home/composer/PeerAdmin@org1 \
  hyperledger/composer-cli:{{COMPOSER-VERSION}} \
  card create -p json/connection1.json -u PeerAdmin -r PeerAdmin -r 
  ChannelAdmin -f /home/composer/vldstage/PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1.card \
  -c PeerAdmin@org1/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k 
  PeerAdmin@org1/keystore/{{PRIV_KEY1}}

docker run \
  --rm \
  --network composer_default \
  -v $(pwd)/.vld-card-store:/home/composer/.composer \
  -v $(pwd)/vldstage:/home/composer/vldstage \
  -v $(pwd)/fabric-dev-servers/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp:/home/composer/PeerAdmin@org1 \
  hyperledger/composer-cli:{{COMPOSER-VERSION}} \
  card import -f vldstage/PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1.card --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1

# build the PeerAdmin card for org2 and import it
docker run \
  --rm \
  --network composer_default \
  -v $(pwd)/.vld-card-store:/home/composer/.composer \
  -v $(pwd)/vldstage:/home/composer/vldstage \
  -v $(pwd)/json:/home/composer/json \
  -v $(pwd)/fabric-dev-servers/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp:/home/composer/PeerAdmin@org2 \
  hyperledger/composer-cli:{{COMPOSER-VERSION}} \
  card create -p json/connection2.json -u PeerAdmin -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin -f /home/composer/vldstage/PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2.card \
  -c PeerAdmin@org2/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem -k PeerAdmin@org2/keystore/{{PRIV_KEY2}}

docker run \
  --rm \
  --network composer_default \
  -v $(pwd)/.vld-card-store:/home/composer/.composer \
  -v $(pwd)/vldstage:/home/composer/vldstage \
  -v $(pwd)/fabric-dev-servers/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp:/home/composer/PeerAdmin@org2 \
  hyperledger/composer-cli:{{COMPOSER-VERSION}} \
  card import -f /home/composer/vldstage/PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2.card --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2

# Install the business network archive on both orgs
docker run \
  --rm \
  --network composer_default \
  -v $(pwd)/vehicle-manufacture-network.bna:/home/composer/vehicle-manufacture-network.bna \
  -v $(pwd)/vldstage:/home/composer/vldstage \
  -v $(pwd)/.vld-card-store:/home/composer/.composer \
  hyperledger/composer-cli:{{COMPOSER-VERSION}} \
  network install -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -a vehicle-manufacture-network.bna

docker run \
  --rm \
  --network composer_default \
  -v $(pwd)/vehicle-manufacture-network.bna:/home/composer/vehicle-manufacture-network.bna \
  -v $(pwd)/vldstage:/home/composer/vldstage \
  -v $(pwd)/.vld-card-store:/home/composer/.composer \
  hyperledger/composer-cli:{{COMPOSER-VERSION}} \
  network install -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2 -a vehicle-manufacture-network.bna
```

Then for the second installation command, i have this following error.

```
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from 
any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: 
Connect Failed
```

And I can't find why. Both connection profile seems to be alright. 
I also checked that the container knows the address of peer0.org2.example.com. So I can't find the issue why it doesn't work on this peer.

Also it seems that when running the second command, i have no logs on peer0.org2.example.com, (but i do on peer0.org1.example.com)

If anyone reading this can help, i'll be glad Thanks

EDIT : For more information

Json for org2

```
{
"name": "composer_default",
"x-type": "hlfv1",
"x-commitTimeout": 100,
"version": "1.0.0",
"client": {
    "organization": "Org2",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
            },
            "orderer": "300"
        }
    }
},
"channels": {
        "composerchannel": {
                "orderers": [
                        "orderer.example.com"
                ],
                "peers": {
                        "peer0.org1.example.com": {},
                        "peer0.org2.example.com": {}
                }
        }
},
"organizations": {
        "Org1": {
                "mspid": "Org1MSP",
                "peers": [
                        "peer0.org1.example.com"
                ],
                "certificateAuthorities": [
                        "ca.org1.example.com"
                ]
        },
        "Org2": {
                "mspid": "Org2MSP",
                "peers": [
                        "peer0.org2.example.com"
                ],
                "certificateAuthorities": [
                        "ca.org2.example.com"
                ]
        }
},
"orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
                "url": "grpc://orderer.example.com:7050"
        }
},
"peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
                "url": "grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7051",
                "eventUrl": "grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7053",
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
        },
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
                "url": "grpc://peer0.org2.example.com:8051",
                "eventUrl": "grpc://peer0.org2.example.com:8053",
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
        }
},
"certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
                "url": "http://ca.org1.example.com:7054",
                "caName": "ca-org1",
                "httpOptions": {
                        "verify": false
                }
        },
        "ca.org2.example.com": {
                "url": "http://ca.org2.example.com:8054",
                "caName": "ca-org2",
                "httpOptions": {
                        "verify": false
                }
        }
}}
```

diff between connection profile :

```
lgrondin@ING-OPS-009:/c/workspace/car_project/packages/vehicle-manufacture/composer-data-latest(multi_node)$ diff json/connection1.json json/connection2.json
7c7
<               "organization": "Org1",
---
>               "organization": "Org2",
```

`composer card list -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2` (from a container like above with same shared volume)

```
userName:            PeerAdmin
description:
businessNetworkName:
identityId:          
3c9251164b9da0021268a2bba92290eaa3787dd436ebc30c6bb481552b7323bf
roles:
  - PeerAdmin
  - ChannelAdmin
connectionProfile:
  name:   composer_default
  x-type: hlfv1
credentials:         Credentials set

Command succeeded
```

No logs on `ca.org2.example.com` no logs on `orderer.example.com` after the install commands on org2

`docker network inspect composer_default`

```
[
{
    "Name": "composer_default",
    "Id": "22d4c9d7238309f7b788b898b718f624f42ab43fd07d419b93c1dff561a8f983",
    "Created": "2018-05-30T14:30:28.0377023Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "1424e6759d96fc75f892196d97a643ef0f48c066299dd8403d3d6e7bc56e88dc": {
            "Name": "orderer.example.com",
            "EndpointID": "0259ad551cb7202282b63f39ea9e3e6d92e2372125bc7923a6acfa378d51be75",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "2b8333cfd852f9c276de25e67f6adffed902ef373eb185f70713faaa31ad3589": {
            "Name": "cli",
            "EndpointID": "365df656aad0a1990527532e2066f603c3c4c0a875e86c4a1fc544eda1884fa8",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:09",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.9/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "7909047abe277b2d77a8e3455a6adaed25c4bed4d661c247b3388e9e29d0d15f": {
            "Name": "hardcore_almeida",
            "EndpointID": "80af1d145fa8ec8e2d59652c32c44c7cb310ae3dc83f10b196b1c14bc5e76ef3",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:0a",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.10/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "79c7d18dcd256bfadf7b31157aeccc5c31b8bf45c542ac837bcb9a66c40260d4": {
            "Name": "ca.org2.example.com",
            "EndpointID": "9cccf7677f22e17dd3341e1ef6de96a84a6e44425c4f5e15f2be7976ecc2e399",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "834172e897a97d9eddcc5f12bf94076313dc1dc259094490c044dd08fbe1cdb4": {
            "Name": "peer0.org2.example.com",
            "EndpointID": "d946f6b445cec7507e8fa995866284ad424e1138c3d0c5210561d7f0e59b09d3",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:07",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.7/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "8731b15759abc6bb60f00e487dc06bdac988ac9d93a0bc89e11d0ff5710689e3": {
            "Name": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "EndpointID": "e3105664d8f9296b027d4401fffabacb28cc12ef841e455cf08363fb83eea5f6",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:08",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.8/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "b09d2d344ac60dc13d4f6c3bc19ec3eee7ab0af40bd4e3a948272167773507b3": {
            "Name": "couchdb1",
            "EndpointID": "79f5bf383e5812f200f35d08d953fcc21fbb2981f986cd8ddf449abd1ab38dda",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:06",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.6/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "be1cb4046af5fa32166ef6db6d9be41f9d53ff1a5d197b9ebe4fedd72cd7b345": {
            "Name": "ca.org1.example.com",
            "EndpointID": "1916d4a04c54259a3366ce73237ef02e191a0856716b3cd1dedbe9f063b8ff88",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "c9b3405f9789438509cdbab71d8515ea33ba0cf5340892da9365eb8762ae93cb": {
            "Name": "couchdb2",
            "EndpointID": "4651a768d9dd494be0fb33202d9b316401b319db2dd46881013e9fe3b8eacb42",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}]
```

`docker ps`

```
lgrondin@ING-OPS-009:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
7909047abe27        hyperledger/composer-cli:latest           "/bin/sh"                3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                         hardcore_almeida
2b8333cfd852        hyperledger/fabric-tools                  "/bin/bash -c './scr…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes                                                        cli
8731b15759ab        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0      "peer node start"        20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
834172e897a9        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0      "peer node start"        20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
79c7d18dcd25        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                           ca.org2.example.com
b09d2d344ac6        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb1
c9b3405f9789        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6984->5984/tcp       couchdb2
1424e6759d96        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0   "orderer"                20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
be1cb4046af5        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
```

Comment: Please can you post the connection.json file for org2, and the output of " docker inspect composer_default " and finally the output of " docker ps ".  (And for completeness for other readers, can you post the info we just shared on Rocket Chat)

Comment: I have completed my post with eveything you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the information !

I think the error is that originally you had localhost in all the URLs including the Ports that were unique to the host machine.  But of course localhost means something different within a container, so you changed the addresses to point to the names provided by Docker Compose and the docker network bridge called "composer_default".

In your connection.json for ORG2 you are referring to the Ports that are forwarded by the docker host, but your context is now from a container so you need to use the port numbers exposed by the containers, not the docker host.

So for example you need to change the port number of the peer for Org2 to be

"url":"grpc://peer0.org2.example.com:7051"

and similarly all the URLs for Org2 need fixing in the same way.

Comment: Thanks ! It was the case now it works ! Now you have said it, it's kinda obvious :)